# show/hide divs based on drop-downs with dynamically generated id

Tags: jquery, html, css, drop-down-menu, show-hide

I'm trying to set up a mechanism where I have multiple select dropdowns on a page, followed by divs by that are shown or hidden based on the active selection. These dropdowns and divs, and their values, are dynamically pulled from on a database.

Currently, I'm using the following jquery script.

```
jQuery(document).ready(function () {

    jQuery(".drop-down-show-hide").hide();

    jQuery("#dropDown").change(function () {
       jQuery(".drop-down-show-hide").hide(); 
       jQuery("#" + this.value).show();
    });
  });
```

And the following html code;

```
<select id="dropDown">
<option>Select...</option>
<option value="choice-1">Choice 1</option>
<option value="choice-2">Choice 2</option>
<option value="choice-3">Choice 3</option>
</select>
<div id="choice-1" class="drop-down-show-hide">content</div>
<div id="choice-2" class="drop-down-show-hide">content</div>
<div id="choice-3" class="drop-down-show-hide">content</div>

<select id="dropDown">
<option>Select...</option>
<option value="choice-4">Choice 4</option>
<option value="choice-5">Choice 5</option>
</select>
<div id="choice-4" class="drop-down-show-hide">content</div>
<div id="choice-5" class="drop-down-show-hide">content</div>
```

With this, only the first dropdown works as desired: selecting one of the choices will show that choice and hide the others. The other dropdown doesn't function - it won't show choices 4 or 5. It also doesn't hide choices 1-3, so this dropdown isn't working at all.

The behavior that I'd actually like to achieve is where each dropdown show/hides only the divs that are given as options. I should be able to give each dropdown a unique id based on the database, so you'd have something like;

```
<select id="uniquevalue1">
<select id="uniquevalue2">
```

My question, then, is how to tailor the jquery so that it can read and process the unique values. I can't hard code the unique id values into the script (like I did with dropDown") because they are pulled on the fly from a database. Is there a way to rewrite the jquery to apply the desired behavior to any dropdown on the page, or an alternative means?

Comment: use class instead of id

Comment: Thanks, that made the second dropdown work, but now i need to resolve the next step of limiting the show/hide mechanism to the divs contained in the dropdown only.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change `id` of `select` to class instead. `id` should always be unique in `DOM`. But `class` can be applied to multiple elements

**[DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/Guruprasad_Rao/doa2xkbe/)**

```
<select class="dropDown">
      ...
</select>
<select class="dropDown">
     ....
</select>
```

and then your same code works!

---

**UPDATE**

To achieve your current requirement I suggest you to group your dropdowns as below:

```
<div class="group"> <!--group each select and subsequent divs into a container-->
    <select class="dropDown">
        <option>Select...</option>
        <option value="choice-1">Choice 1</option>
        <option value="choice-2">Choice 2</option>
        <option value="choice-3">Choice 3</option>
    </select>
    <div id="choice-1" class="drop-down-show-hide">content1</div>
    <div id="choice-2" class="drop-down-show-hide">content2</div>
    <div id="choice-3" class="drop-down-show-hide">content3</div>
</div>
<div class="group"> <!--Same here for 2nd dropdown-->
    <select class="dropDown">
        <option>Select...</option>
        <option value="choice-4">Choice 4</option>
        <option value="choice-5">Choice 5</option>
    </select>
    <div id="choice-4" class="drop-down-show-hide">content4</div>
    <div id="choice-5" class="drop-down-show-hide">content5</div>
</div>
```

**JS** you can update a single line in `change` event:

```
jQuery(".dropDown").change(function () {
       jQuery(this).closest('.group').find(".drop-down-show-hide").hide(); 
       //find select's parent and hide its corresponding divs only
       jQuery("#" + this.value).show();
});
```

**[DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/Guruprasad_Rao/doa2xkbe/1/)**

Comment: Although -- there is still a piece missing. Right now both of the dropdowns are working, but they are hiding the others' divs. This is what I was describing at the end. I would like for the dropdown to only hide the divs that are given as options, and my theory is that the best way to do this is using unique id's (or classes) for the dropdowns. And then to describe those identifiers to jquery.

Comment: Anytime @astrosa happy coding.. :)